# How ddns client work?

Tags: networking

I get corious about how ddns client work,
I have router and netbook with ddns client installed.
If i type mydomain.ddns.com (provide by ddns host) , my browser direct to my netbook's webhost.

If i read about the flow ddns client, ddns client sent my public ip to ddns server, and when i type mydomain.ddns.com the dns will ask ddns server to get my ip.

But it just my public ip right? When someone access it, it should be access the router not my netbook?  Why it can redirect from router to my pc? I'm not setting any ddns or port forwarding on my router. Is ddns client using tunneling or something?

And i after google to know my public ip, why i cant simply access my router with my public ip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DDNS clients update the DNS server with your current public IP as you mentioned. since your laptop is behind a router - its uses the router public IP to go out to the internet, so the DNS server actually holds a record of your.ddns.com that points to your **router** IP address. Its up to you ( and your router configuration ) to decide if incoming IP traffic to that address on a given port should or shouldnt be forwarded to the internal laptop.
If you cannot access your router, check its configuration - some security features disables access from the internet (**external interface**) by default.

Comment: Yes but my  ddns work even i did not configure any port forwarding, why it can work like that?it still work even i use my friend's wifi

Comment: ddns client has nothing to do with port forwarding. its just mapping IP<->HOST . please provide more details, and what did you try to test with your friend's wifi ?

Comment: Oh wait i see now, thanks for your help